# How intelligent would a real life fairy be?

Tags: fantasy-races, intelligence

Because fairies are rather small, I'm assuming they wouldn’t be able to be all that intelligent. what I’m wondering, however, is *just how intelligent*? Let’s say that they’re about the size of a hummingbird. Logically, how intelligent can a hummingbird-sized being be? Assume no magic.

Comment: It's your world. You get to choose how intelligent they are. They can be dumb as literal rocks or they could be so intellectually advanced that their motivations are alien to us mere mortals.

Comment: I think you're looking for encephalization quotient https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encephalization_quotient

Answer (score 5):

Size doesn't correlate directly to intelligence. Crows, for example, are among the smartest creatures in the world apart from humans, having intelligence approximating that of a seven year old child ([link](https://www.nathab.com/blog/crows-are-as-intelligent-as-a-seven-year-old-child/)).

Little is actually understood about the advantages associated with brain size, but some studies show that larger brains improve performance under pressure ([link](http://sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/05/150522105333.htm)) and neurogenesis ([link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5047485/)). Better neurogenesis means that adults are still able to learn quickly, it means that individuals are capable of specializing in a more broad and various set of behaviors (as opposed to being limited to only being good at a few things), and it means that we're able to retain more information in memory.

That doesn't mean that a small creature couldn't compensate for short memory and poor potential by simply being very clever; it's conceivable that a minimal working set of cognitive functions, specialized in communication and rapid inference, would enable a small creature to quickly generate reasonable assumptions on moderate sets of data, and then selectively discard the data in favor of keeping the result. Such a creature could closely emulate a human, while simply seeming naive, and appearing to have little regard for detail. While we might remember a significant event because it seems important, your fairies might only draw and remember impulsive conclusions based on the event (i.e. without remembering how they learned the information, a fairy might remember: "person X is untrustworthy, and person Y has lots of treasure in his house"; or perhaps more broadly, they might forget the people altogether and remember, "persons wearing red are untrustworthy, and there's treasure over there"), and then discard most information about the event itself, causing them to seem careless or lacking in mature values.

Comment: So, they would lack memory of details? If so, could they perhaps write notes down before they forget, so that they’d have the details incase they need them?

Comment: @user79037 Yeah, they could do that if they were inclined to. However, I imagine they'd be naturally adapted to their native environment in such a way that they don't need to remember detailed events in order to carry on normally. On first exposure to the human world, they might be totally disinterested in details, and only start taking notes like that if it becomes a necessity for survival (such as if humans colonize the natural fairy habitat and enforce their culture on the fairies).

Answer (score 0):

I'm no biologist so take of my answer what you will.

I think they can be fairly smart if you properly handle their background.

Lets examine a human dwarf, they are not that large.
Yet a human dwarf is as smart as a regular human.

Now I'm aware that a human dwarf is the exception here BUT what if the background for you early fairy capitalized on that?

Lets assume that the older fairies were actually larger, but the environment was not suited for larger fairies.

So random gene or mutation hits a bunch and they are a lot more suites for the early fairy environment.
So we start getting our good old loop of X appears and later generation prefer X so they breed for X and thus X becomes more dominant.

So just say they existed in some sort of miniature city like environment or whatever you can so that their early smaller ancestors have an advantage.

Now we humans are large but not the largest by any chance.

Yes the coloration between brain size and intelligence is there, afaik.

But lets examine other animals we consider intelligent.

Parrots, ravens, dolphins, chimps...etc

Are fairly smart, not human smart, and they are quite small in size.

Also the material of their (fairies ) brain and nervous can simply be better.

Think of an Intel , just a famous example and AMD is as good as Intel now,
processor. Something like a core I3 as opposed to a core I7 of the same gen.
They have the same exact size, afaik, yet the core I7 is better.

A CPU is actually accurate as it does calculate stuff and can somewhat resemble a brain.

So it's not the size of the CPU/GPU/Brain/Muscle...etc but rather what's in there.

You can also see this in many animals who are much smaller than humans yet possess greater strength.

So that's about the extent of my biology knowledge.

I'm sure others can provide you with exact equations and numbers.

Comment: Question- does that also mean that they may have the same lifespan as a human?

Comment: Newer silicon having more transistors in the same area directly corresponds to neuron density, which varies quite widely in nature. Fairies having a similar number of neurons to humans might be pushing it, but it *sounds* somewhat plausible. Crows are smarter than whales, after all.

Comment: @user79037, 
Again from a an enthusiast writers prospective I' say it would depend on the setting.
There are some small animals, birds, and fish that "long" lifespans.
So he make them quite malleable with the ability to extend their lifespans or decided to have them small sized short lived fairies then he can.
As long as it is plausible and does not completely break science.

Comment: @StephenS,
Yes. Size matters to an extent. 
But if they can't have the pure size then their neurons are "better" than humans. 
Or a compromise of both.
Again like how two CPUs of the same exact size can be so very different so can biology. 
And like you said "plausible" is the key word here. He is making a story not trying to actually create fairies in a lab.
Heck. Even in biology we don't know the limits. 
We can only study the creatures we have access to and examine what we know.

Comment: Humans with dwarfish still have similar-sized brains as regular-sized humans. Even very young children have skulls big enough for adult human brains. That particular analogy is fairly meaningless.

Comment: @Matthew,
Maybe I was not clear.
I meant that I was trying to disagree with the idea that it's always the overall size of the creature.
Starting from human dwarves and moved from there.
Maybe I should have compared them to elephants or something to make it clear.
Anyway I only meant that you can have a small animal with X properties so  size is not the only factor here.
Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: @user79037 Lifespan is a separate question, but you may want to wait until intelligence is settled here since that is a factor.

Comment: @Seallussus, I suppose that works for showing that body size ≠ brain size, but your point seemed to be that "humans with dwarfism are just as intelligent as other humans", to which I thought "well, of course they are, their brains are essentially the same". (Also, I expect everyone already knows that brain size ≠ body size. Plus, fairies as described by the OP obviously can't have human-sized brains.) Your later points as to brain size ≠ intelligence are much more useful.

Comment: @Matthew,
But even humans as creatures are not the largest which is related.
Think of it this way: there are many animals larger than humans and humans are smart, dwarf humans are even smaller and still OVERALL smarter than other animals which are bigger.
Anyway maybe it did not make much sense. 
OP does not seem to consider it useful so it's moot point anyway